# How do I rearrange the data in a ListView?

Tags: java, android

I have an EditText in which the user puts numbers. The box then sends the data to a ListView with a Button's help. I would like to make the ListView rearrange its data to have the numbers sorted from the smallest to the biggest.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Sort your data before passing to the listview adapter.

For future questions, please paste some code that you have tried to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

ListView was also filled by an Adapter, right?
Then it works like this.

Write a comperator for your data type, dont know if there are premade ones for int.

```
Comparator<MyClass> comparator_date = new Comparator<MyClass>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(MyClasslhs, MyClassrhs) {
        int compare_score;
        compare_score = lhs.yourCompareFunction(rhs);
        //replace with a function that compares your type and returns an int
        return compare_score;
    }
};
```

Now you can call the sorting method on your list, with your comparator.

```
Collections.sort(releasedEpisodeList, comparator_name);
```

And tell the adapter to update your listview

```
Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

This way you can update your ListView after creation.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have some `Arraylist` of integers or strings?

You can `Collections.sort(list)`, then `adapter.notifyDatasetChanged()` to tell the ListView to "redraw".

If the list contains integers, this will sort from "smallest to largest", if the list contains strings, then it will sort "lexicographically", or alphabetically.